# Added vinegar and dish soap to kill clover. but it killed my grass. What should I do?

Tags: lawn, weed-control, lawn-repair

I heard that it doesn't kill the root so grass should regrow. I used 5% acidic vinegar.

Answer (score 2):

The vinegar and dish soap may not have killed the clover either - vinegar is acetic acid and acts as a herbicide on the green parts of a plant, but unless you saturated the soil with it, it won't kill the roots, so its likely both the grass and the clover will regrow.

You don't say where you are in the world; here in the UK, there are no weedkillers available that kill clover, but Verdone II (now called Weedol lawn weedkiller) gives some control of clover without killing grass, since it is a weedkiller intended for use on lawns. You will need to wait until the grass has regrown fully before using it though.

Comment: Im in the U.S. How long will it take for the grass to regrow

Comment: Hard to be sure, depends how much vinegar you got on the soil, but probably 3-6 weeks.